# Install Ubuntu (or any Distro) on a Windows 8.1 Tablet

Tags: drivers, system-installation, windows, bootloader, tablet

I've been thinking about getting a cheap x86 Windows tablet and install Ubuntu and/or other distros on it. I'm not sure if there's anything fundamentally wrong, but being x86 devices it should be possible to install any OS on them.
Does anyone have any experience with this? I imagine driver support could be a problem, or locked bootloaders.
Are there any recommendations for tablets to use? My budget is up to around €170, ideally as low as possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scope of this site doesn't covers hardware recommendations  and I pretty much doubt you can run Ubuntu in a random cheap tablet with Windows preinstalled unless all hardware drivers are aviable either from part of the maker (doubt it) or the comunity.  Here is a list of hardware supliers who sell computers with Ubuntu preinstalled, some list Tablets aviable. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed